# Pan and Tap gesture is not working inside the flutter TabviewController

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gesture, tabview

I have used a GestureDetector which is placed inside TabViewController. In that, the Pan and Tap events of Gesture Detector are not working and instead of that the drag and tap event of TabViewController is working. How to make the events of gesture detector to work?

I have referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61221798/gesturedetector-is-not-working-on-top-of-tabbarview) but in that only the solution for avoiding the overridden of tap gesture of the corresponding widget has provided

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(length: 3, child: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _value = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size(200, 200)),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onPanStart: (DragStartDetails details) =>
                                {print('pan start')},
                            onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) =>
                            {print('pan update')},
                            onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) =>
                            {print('pan end')},
                            onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) =>
                            {print('tap up')},
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Slider(
                        value: _value.toDouble(),
                        min: 1.0,
                        max: 10.0,
                        divisions: 10,
                        activeColor: Colors.red,
                        inactiveColor: Colors.black,
                        label: 'Set a value',
                        onChanged: (double newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _value = newValue.round();
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Slider(
                        value: _value.toDouble(),
                        min: 1.0,
                        max: 10.0,
                        divisions: 10,
                        activeColor: Colors.red,
                        inactiveColor: Colors.black,
                        label: 'Set a value',
                        onChanged: (double newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _value = newValue.round();
                          });
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the scrolling of `TabBarView` to still be intact ? What action are you going to perform on `pan start`, `pan update` and `pan end` ?

Comment: @Darshan:  We don't need TabBarView  interact as like slider behavior when adding it in TabBarView. We will add custom painter under GestureDetector and will do some interaction like dragging using pan start, pan update.