# How do I implement correctly`HitTestBehavior.translucent`in a gesture detector?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, gesturedetector

given the code below

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context) async => showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Success'),
        content: const Text('nice job!'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('done'),
            onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 25,
              right: 25,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(Icons.message),
                onPressed: () => _showMyDialog(context),
              ),
            ),
            PageView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  child: const ColoredBox(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(60, 30, 10, .5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

how do I make the button clickable without changing the order of the children in the stack and keeping the scroll view scrollable?

I have tried wrapping the `PageView` in a `GestureDetector` without results

```
  GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              onTap: null,
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ...
              ),
            ),
```

[flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100619)

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Answer

The problem is `PageView` takes up the whole screen.
There is no visible part of `FloatingActionButton` regarding gesture events.

If you don't want to change the order of your stack children's widgets, you have to change the `PageView` area.

Below is the updated code snippet.
The `PageView` is scrollable but only in its area. The `FloatingActionButton` is clickable.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context) async => showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Success'),
        content: const Text('nice job!'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('done'),
            onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 25,
              right: 25,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(Icons.message),
                onPressed: () => _showMyDialog(context),
              ),
            ),
    
            Positioned(     //// <------  
 //// The page ends before it can cover the floating action button.
 /// But if the screen size changes, you might have to see how to make it work.

              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ColoredBox(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(60, 30, index * 100, .5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

You can have a global PageView controller to set the scrollable functionality outside of the pageview area.

---

#### Old Answer

Wrap the `PageView` (the top widget which must be transparent to any tap) with `IgnorePointer` and set the `ignoring` field to `true`.

This will make the `FloatingActionButton` (the down widget) listen to tap events.

Here is the code snippet with change:

```dart
...
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(Icons.message),
                onPressed: () => _showMyDialog(context),
              ),
            ),


            IgnorePointer(    /// <---------- Wrap with IgnorePointer
              ignoring: true,

              child: PageView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: const ColoredBox(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(60, 30, 10, .5),
                    ),
                  ),
...
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945252/9468577) for reference.

Comment: hi, this will make the page view non scrollable :(

Comment: You want both the top widget and bottom widget clickable?

Comment: that's the goal for `HitTestBehavior.translucent` afaik
I've updated the description, you are right, it wasn't precise

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully, it is what you are looking for.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450) to understand more about hit behavior. It is a little confusing. ;)